# How do I get Realtek HD Audio Manager

Tags: windows-10, audio, download

When I built my computer, Realtek HD Audio Manager was not installed by default, which was never an issue until I got new headphones, and now I need to change some settings. I don't have any files related to Realtek on my computer; how do I install it? (I'm running Windows 10.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Program Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA. Double-click on RtkNGUI64.exe. You will find Realtek HD, audio manager. If you still can't find Realtek audio manager, then you may need to reinstall Realtek audio manager by updating your Realtek HD audio driver.